# React.js - update data in JSON server with PATCH method with state value

Tags: reactjs, json-server

for learning purposes I'm creating a CRUD todo list with React and JSON-server. I got stuck with PATCH method, as it only updates data in JSON-server on the first click. I want to update the data with the component's state value.

Service file with requests:

```
const serverAddress = 'http://localhost:8000';
const collection = 'todoItems';

const fetchAll = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(`${serverAddress}/${collection}`);
  const todoItems = response.json();

  return todoItems;
};

const complete = async (id) => {
const completed = {
  completed : true
}

// how to set the 'completed' value in json-server based on item's state? 

const response = await fetch(`${serverAddress}/${collection}/${id}`, {
  method: 'PATCH',
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(completed ),
  });

 const data = await response.json();

 return data;
}

const TodoItemsService = {
  fetchAll,
  create,
  remove,
  complete
};

export default TodoItemsService;
```

Card component which holds all todo items:

```
const Card = () => {
const [todoItems, setTodoItems] = useState([]);

const fetchAllTodoItems = async () => {
  const fetchedTodoItems = await TodoItemsService.fetchAll();
  setTodoItems(fetchedTodoItems);
};

useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    fetchAllTodoItems();
  })();
}, []);

const handleComplete = async (id) => {
  await TodoItemsService.complete(id);
}

return (
  <div className='card'>
    <CardHeader />
    <AddTodoForm onAddTodoItem={handleAddTodoItem} />
    <TodoItemsContainer
      todoItems={todoItems}
      onDelete={handleDelete}
      onComplete={handleComplete}
    />
  </div>
 )
}

export default Card;
```

TodoItemsContainer component

```
const TodoItemsContainer = ({ todoItems, onDelete, onComplete }) => {

return (
  <div className='todo-items-container'>
    {todoItems.length === 0 &&
      <div className='empty'>
        <img src={NoTodoItems} alt="" />
      </div>}
    {todoItems.map(({ id, text }) => (
      <TodoItem
        key={id}
        id={id}
        text={text}
        onDelete={onDelete}
        onComplete={onComplete}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
 )
}

export default TodoItemsContainer;
```

TodoItem component

```
const TodoItem = ({ id, text, onDelete, onComplete }) => {
const [isComplete, setIsComplete] = useState(false);

const handleIsCompleteById = () => {
  onComplete(id);
  setIsComplete(!isComplete);
};

const handleDeleteTodoItemById = () => {
  onDelete(id);
};

return (
  <div className={`todo-item ${isComplete ? 'complete' : ''}`}>
    <p>{text}</p>
  <div>
     <TodoItemComplete onComplete={handleIsCompleteById}/>
     <TodoItemDelete onDelete={handleDeleteTodoItemById}/>
   </div>
  </div>
 )
}

export default TodoItem;
```

TodoItemComplete button component

```
const TodoItemComplete = ({ onComplete }) => {

return (
  <button type='button' onClick={onComplete}>
    <div className='icon'>
      {<SVGComplete />}
    </div>
  </button>
  )
}

export default TodoItemComplete;
```

From React perspective it works fine, it marks the item as complete based on state, but I also want to reflect todo item's status as complete in my json-server. Does anyone have any tips or can see the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Simply had to pass the state as the second param in complete service and other functions that handle complete action.